# Creating a marquee using anything? Javascript, Jquery, CSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a blog using HTML and CSS. Now I've integrated API's for certain stocks using PHP and using the data I've created multiple widgets.

Now I'm trying to create a marquee similar to stock markets (endless and infinite without any gaps). I found a few examples on the but failed to understand its implementation.

Can anyone tell how the marquee like feature works in either of these websites

1. https://nse.com/ (at the top of the website)
2. https://www.gdax.com/

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    refreshData();
})

function refreshData() {
    $('#container-table').load("data.php", function(){
        setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
    });

    $('#container-tablel').load("datanike.php", function(){
        setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
    });

    $('#container-tabled').load("datamsft.php", function(){
        setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
    });

    $('#container-tablee').load("dataaapple.php", function(){
        setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
    });

    $('#container-tablex').load("dataamzn.php", function(){
        setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
    <div id="container-table"></div>
    <div id="container-tablel"></div>
    <div id="container-tabled"></div>
    <div id="container-tablee"></div>
    <div id="container-tablex"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to implement these like the one in GDAX. But any other implementation will also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) recommending sortware is expressly Off Topic

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple html <**marquee**> tag for infinite moving.

See example:

```css
#container-table, #container-tablel, #container-tabled, #container-tablee, #container-tablex {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <marquee>
      <div id="container-table">test</div>
      <div id="container-tablel">test1</div>
      <div id="container-tabled">test2</div>
      <div id="container-tablee">test3</div>
      <div id="container-tablex">test4</div>
  </marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: <marquee>: "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

This is continuous marquee

```js
// polyfill
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var speed = 5000;
(function currencySlide(){
    var currencyPairWidth = $('.slideItem:first-child').outerWidth();
    $(".slideContainer").animate({marginLeft:-currencyPairWidth},speed, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).css({marginLeft:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(currencySlide);
})();
```

```css
.slider{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
.edge{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
.edge:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 10%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
}
.edge:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, white 10%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
}
ul{
    background:#ddd;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000%;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slider'>
    <div class="edge"></div>
<ul class="slideContainer" id="money_start">
        <li class="slideItem" >
                EUR
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                USD
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                JPY
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                CNY
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                VD
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                GBP
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                AUD
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                CAD
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                CHF
        </li>
        <li class="slideItem">
                XAU
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The NSE site is using [custom-stock-ticker](https://github.com/wp-plugins/custom-stock-ticker) (A Word Press Plugin). A good place to start there is looking at `stock_ticker_script.js`.